# CacheSizes node vs cache settings in site definition

Tags: caching, site-configuration

I'm setting up a bunch of site definitions for my project. I know I need to add them all to the publish:end and publish:end:remote events to clear caching. But when it comes to the entries in `<cacheSizes><sites>` these seem to be duplicates of entries in the site definition item. Are both needed for a site, or can what's in the site definition suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cache settings in the site definition override the cache settings in cacheSizes node. Therefore, settings that apply to all sites should be made in the cacheSizes node, and then site-specific settings in the site definition.